Is it haram to join Discord servers dedicated to movies?
I met a lot of friends on a Discord server for a Disney movie that contains music. Would it be haram to stay in that server (even if I don’t talk about the movie there), and would it be haram to stay friends with the people I met there (even if they aren’t pushing me to sin)?
